# C++: How do I make std::istream take input from keyboard

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm making a console game and am trying to implement highscores. So I prompt someone to enter their name and since I want to display it to them while they're typing I need some way to link my screen buffer to the keyboard. BTW the other question with this name has nothing to do with the topic.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code...

Comment: You need platform specific code to do that. There are some libraries which can help, like `curses`, `ncurses` and `pdcurses`.

Comment: Keyboard and / or mouse input can not be read though iostreams. The best you can get is some escape sequences written as regular bytes.

Comment: well the screen buffer is an array of wchar_t screen [screenWidth*screenHeight]. It's output every clocktick by  WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten). So I only need some way to specify that a stream takes input not from some file or std::cin but from the keyboard

Comment: `std::cin` reads from the keyboard and ordinarily displays while the user is typing. It can be passed to a function that takes `std::istream&`.

Comment: Since I'm using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter to render each frame in the console I can't use cin. I need some way to get raw data from the keyboard.

Comment: @skugz -- you need to say in your question that you're doing system-specific (i.e., non-portable) stuff. That way, people can tell you that you're making things harder for yourself. <g>

Comment: Ok, noted. Any suggestions on the question though?